# Need to insert array data using laravel controller

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

i have a array data like this below. i want to save some of it's data not all into mysql table.
when i `dd($request->all)` data in my controller function it looks like this.

```
array:1 [
  "{"cart":" => array:1 [
    "{"product":{"id":1,"category":1,"product_name":"Brinjal 500g","product_image":"1585409454.jpeg","product_price":232,"unit":"500g","product_description":null,"stock":"In Stock","product_status":1,"show":1,"delievery_date":null,"vendor":null,"quantity":18,"item_type":"feature_product","created_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:54.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:54.000000Z","deleted_at":null,"categories":{"id":1,"category_name":"Fresh Fruits","category_image":null,"category_description":null,"category_status":1,"show":0,"created_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:12.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:12.000000Z","deleted_at":null}},"quantity":1}" => null
  ]
]
```

i want to add id and total quantity shows last object into a table. table rows looks like this.

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('order_id');
$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('total_quantity');
$table->timestamps();
$table->softDeletes();
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```

how can i write a store function using this data in laravel

result data looks like this

```
Array
(
    [{"cart":] => Array
        (
            [{"product":{"id":1,"category":1,"product_name":"Brinjal 500g","product_image":"1585409454.jpeg","product_price":232,"unit":"500g","product_description":null,"stock":"In Stock","product_status":1,"show":1,"delievery_date":null,"vendor":null,"quantity":18,"item_type":"feature_product","created_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:54.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:54.000000Z","deleted_at":null,"categories":{"id":1,"category_name":"Fresh Fruits","category_image":null,"category_description":null,"category_status":1,"show":0,"created_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:12.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:12.000000Z","deleted_at":null}},"quantity":1}] => 
        )

)
```

this is my latest update

```
$data = [];
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
   $data[$key]['product_id'] = $value['product']['id'];
   $data[$key]['quantity'] = $value['quantity'];
   dd($value);
}
```

Comment: can you `echo '<pre>'; print_r($request->all()); `

Comment: can you (echo '<pre>'; print_r($request->all());) we did not understand your data why id field comes 2 times with same value ?

Comment: @DilipHirapara i updated my question with your request in last columns

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your data coming and make array as below i have shown.

Try this one by creating the array of the data and insert array to the database as bulk data:

```
// this will decode your json data that you're getting in the post data
$postdata = json_decode($request->all(), true);

$data = [];
foreach ($postdata as $key => $value) {        
    $data[$key]['product_id'] = $value['product']['id'];
    $data[$key]['quantity'] = $value['quantity'];
}

// $data now will have data as following structure

$data = [[
    'product_id' => 2,
    'total_quantity' => 7   

],
[
    'product_id' => 2,
    'total_quantity' => 7   

]];

$order = Order::create($data);
```

Comment: i tried this but shows me this error . (json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given)

Comment: @kalana93 so in that you are getting the array in the post so you don't need to include $postdata = json_decode($request->all(), true); this line in your code.

Comment: i removed that line and edit foreach like this.foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) . then it shows this error . Undefined index: product

Comment: @kalana93 can you do dd($value); inside the foreach loop and show me output.

Comment: i  do that. but still shows me "Undefined index: product" error

Comment: @kalana93 can you update your latest code in the question. so that i can have more idea about your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210516/discussion-between-kalana93-and-sarvil-ajwaliya).

Comment: @kalana93 Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.